# Query third-party api on lead update and write response to new field on same object

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, future

Folks, I am in need of some apex wisdom please! I've experience in other programming languages but trying to get my first apex trigger and class set up. My overall aim is when a specific field on the lead gets updated, ping a third-party api, get the result and store it on the Lead.

Through my digging I've got the overall functionality working in that I correctly can make the call and get the data but I'm struggling with the Salesforce/Apex side of things.

The structure I'm using is that a trigger gets called when the field in question is edited. That trigger then calls an @future class which stores the logic. The class makes the query to the API and returns the correct result, however, it's not writing it to the Lead, and instead returns the following error

- "System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id ; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadNumberLookup: execution of BeforeUpdate"
- The same issue occurs when I use after update too in the trigger.

Any advice on the error or pointers towards blogs where I can follow best practice would be greatly appreciated! I know I need to bulkify this flow too so I just need some experience in general. Thanks

**Trigger**

```
trigger LeadNumberLookup on Lead (before update) {

Set <Id> setLeadIds = new Set <Id>();    

 for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
     
     if(l.Phone_Number_Aggregated__c != null && (Trigger.oldMap.get(l.id).Phone_Number_Aggregated__c != l.Phone_Number_Aggregated__c)){
         
         setLeadIds.add(l.id);
         System.debug(setLeadIds);
         
     }
     
 }
 
 NumberLookupGeo.GeoFromPhoneNumber(setLeadIds); 
 System.debug('----call made to apex class ----'); }
```

**Class**

```
public class NumberLookupGeo {

@future(callout=true)
public static void GeoFromPhoneNumber(Set<Id> leadIds) {
    
    List<Lead> leadRecords = [Select Phone_Number_Aggregated__c from Lead where id = :leadIds];
    
    for ( Lead l : leadRecords){
    
        String phone_num = l.Phone_Number_Aggregated__c;
        String iso_country_code = '';
        String iso_country = '';
        String state = '';
        String city = '';
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.telnyx.com/v2/number_lookup/' + phone_num);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer xxxxxx');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
            Map<String, Object> json = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            // Get the main key, 'data', in the JSON dictionary
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)json.get('data');
            // Inside 'data', 'country_code' is a main
            iso_country_code = (String) data.get('country_code');
            //System.debug(data.get('country_code'));
            // state and city are key-values within the portability dictionary
            Map<String,Object> portability = (Map<String,Object>)data.get('portability');
            // State and city may not exist or return values for multiple countries
            
            try {
                state = (String) portability.get('state');
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('State - The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
                }   
            try {
                String city_unformatted = (String) portability.get('city');
                List<String> names = city_unformatted.toLowerCase().split(' ');
                for (Integer i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
                    names[i] = names[i].capitalize();
                    city = String.join(names, ' ');
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('City - The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            
            // There is an Apex class called 'ISOLookup' that contains a hardcode map of code to country
            // Calling the Alpha2CodeToCountry with the code as the parameter, returns the corresponding country
            iso_country = ISOLookup.Alpha2CodeToCountry(iso_country_code);
            
            }
            
        // If we don't get a 200-OK response, return the error to the console
        else {
            System.debug('Received Status code ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' from Number Lookup endpoint.');
        }
        
        
        l.Phone_Number_Country__c = iso_country;
        l.Phone_Number_State__c = state; 
        l.Phone_Number_City__c = city; 
        
     }
     
     update leadRecords;
 }}
```

[image]

Comment: Aside from you performing DML (i.e. `insert`, `update`, `upsert`, `delete`, and a few others) inside of a loop (DML and queries are two things that should basically never be done inside of a loop on the Salesforce platform, with very few exceptions), I don't see anything that jumps out as wrong. An update trigger calling a method that updates the same object can lead to an infinite loop, but it looks like that shouldn't be an issue here. Is that the entirety of the error message you're getting? Could you also include the stack trace?

Comment: @DerekF - Thanks for your reply. I have dropped in an image above of the exceptions thrown. I have also updated the code to remove the update from the for loop as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual exception that is thrown before the error you noticed at the end  is seen in the debug log screenshot you shared:

> Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method:
> NumberLookupGeo.GeoFromPhoneNumber(Set)

1. Lead is updated to meet the condition to make the 3rd party call
2. Lead is updated in future method/context
3. Lead trigger runs from the above update (from future method)
4. Your trigger code attempts to call the future method with no values in `setLeadIds`.
5. The above means that your future method (that updated the lead appropriately) is now invoking another future method (in the same update transaction)

Your trigger shouldn't always call the [Future method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) - it should check if there's any need to (any records) before calling it or you risk running into other limits other than the one you're currently running into

> You can invoke future methods the same way you invoke any other
> method. However, a future method can’t invoke another future method.

> The maximum number of future method invocations per a 24-hour period
> is 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your organization
> multiplied by 200, whichever is greater. This limit is for your entire
> org and is shared with all asynchronous Apex: Batch Apex, Queueable
> Apex, scheduled Apex, and future methods.

A simple check to see if the call is even needed will solve your issue

```java
if(setLeadIds.size() > 0){
    NumberLookupGeo.GeoFromPhoneNumber(setLeadIds); 
}
```

Even with that, as Derek mentioned, you'll want to pay attention to how your trigger will handle bulk contexts and play within the Salesforce imposed limits. [Apex Design Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices) is from 2016, but contains a lot of useful notes.

Lastly, it's important to be aware that [Queuable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) exists and provides additional benefits. I don't believe this changes anything with your use-case here as a future method is appropriate, but may be important in future design considerations.

> - Getting an ID for your job: When you submit your job by invoking the
>   System.enqueueJob method, the method returns the ID of the new job.
>   This ID corresponds to the ID of the AsyncApexJob record. Use this ID
>   to identify your job and monitor its progress, either through the
>   Salesforce user interface in the Apex Jobs page, or programmatically
>   by querying your record from AsyncApexJob.
> - Using non-primitive types:
>   Your queueable class can contain member variables of non-primitive
>   data types, such as sObjects or custom Apex types. Those objects can
>   be accessed when the job executes. Chaining jobs: You can chain one
>   job to another job by starting a second job from a running job.
> - Chaining jobs is useful if your process depends on another process to
>   have run first.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Telling the trigger not to run on future/batch calls seems to do the trick. I will now look into queueable able as mentioned by Kris to improve the performance. https://medium.com/@CoachRWZ/salesforce-chaining-queueable-apex-callouts-53615b8dee92